# Javascript Callback Inside Map

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps, asynchronous

I am currently running into a problem when I am trying to return from a callback in a `map` function. As is usually the case with asynchronous code, the map function completes before the async call is complete, meaning I lose my data.

What can I do within the `map` function to ensure the async call is complete? I tried to only return from a promise, but it seems like the map function returns null when it reaches the end.

In my specific example, I am trying to get a bunch of businesses from the Yelp API, and then geocode their individual addresses so that I can add them to a Google Maps map on my website.

Code:

```
Q.Promise(function(resolve, reject, notify) {
  yelp.search({
    category_filter: 'food,restaurants',
    location: city, 
    limit: 3, 
    sort: 2, // sort mode: 2=Highest Rated
  }, function(error, data) {
    if (error) {
      reject(new Error(error));
    }
    else {
      if (data['businesses'] && data['businesses'].length > 0) {
        results = data['businesses'].map(function(business) {
          sleep.usleep(500000); // sleep for 0.5 seconds so as not to get throttled by google
          address = business.location.display_address.join(', ');
          geocoder.geocode(address)
            .then(function(res) {
              return {
                img_url: business.image_url,
                name: business.name,
                url: business.url,
                rating_img_url: business.rating_img_url,
                address: address,
                coords: [res[0]['latitude'], res[0]['longitude']],
              }
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
              console.log('Could not geocode: ' + err);
              return;
            });
        });
        resolve(results);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I hate suggested a less "functional" approach ([see wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming), particularly the part about side effects), but if you're willing to use a simple loop that mutates object properties, it should do the trick:

```
data.forEach(function(business) {
          // code removed
            .then(function(res) {
              business.businesses = /* the new object */
            })
            // code removed
```

In the above approach, you'll simply iterate over `data` and mutate the appropriate `businesses` property of the currently iterated `business`.

I think most other approaches may be a bit convoluted/obfuscated, so this may be a "lesser of evils" type of thing. Other options include storing all your promises in a new array and using something like `Q.allSettled` to match them to the appropriate `business` property. Not sure if that's an optimal approach, though.

Comment: I'm currently toying with the idea of doing a Promise within a Promise (so I will do Q.all(geoQueries)). What do you think about the merits of this solution over yours? Also, why wouldn't forEach fail on async callbacks the  same way map does?

Comment: @tsurantino, I try to avoid a whole promises-within-promises approach because it usually ends up being very un-readable. I think `forEach` doesn't "fail" because the callback inside of `then` is simply storing a reference to the currently-iterated `business`, and when the promise resolves, it invokes the appropriate callback and maps to the appropriate object. I could be wrong, but in the project we're working on now, this pattern is being used more or less "successfully".

Comment: That makes sense! I'm on the go right now so I'm going to post the Promises within Promises approach as another optional answer. I'm going to try your approach when I get home. If it works and is more readable, I will award your answer :) Thanks again for taking the time to reply.

Comment: @tsurantino, sure no prob! Hopefully you find a suitable solution.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Josh Beam's answer, I'm going to post a solution that I thought of, which actually puts the geocoding code into a separate series of promises that are invoked, before returning the results for the Yelp promise. :

```
Q.Promise(function(resolve, reject, notify) {
  yelp.search({
    category_filter: 'food,restaurants',
    location: city, 
    limit: 3, 
    sort: 2, // sort mode: 2=Highest Rated
  }, function(error, data) {
    if (error) {
      reject(new Error(error));
    }
    else {
      if (data['businesses'] && data['businesses'].length > 0) {
        // we only need some of the properties of a Yelp business result
        geoQueries = [];
        results = data['businesses'].map(function(business) {
          geoQueries.push(Q.Promise(function(resolve, reject, notify) {
            // sleep for 0.5 seconds so as not to get throttled by google
            sleep.usleep(500000); 

            address = business.location.display_address.join(', ');
            geocoder.geocode(address)
            .then(function(res) {
              resolve({
                img_url: business.image_url,
                name: business.name,
                url: business.url,
                rating_img_url: business.rating_img_url,
                address: address,
                coords: [res[0]['latitude'], res[0]['longitude']],
              });
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
              console.log('Could not geocode: ' + err);
              return;
            });
          }));
        });

        Q.all(geoQueries)
        .then(function(data) {
          resolve(data);
        });
      }
    }
  });
});
```